# POCO Classes to Code First Database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have POCO classes generated from xsd.exe, now i want to convert these classes to Entity Framework code first database.

I have tried to generate code first database i get error of primary key not included, if i add custom primary key column in that class, database gets generated.

When i try to De-serialize that class to extract the data using that POCO classes, it throws type mismatch error.

I need a way to convert my POCO classes to database and De-serialize that classes to load data and then save to database.

edited

The error i get is "There was an error reflecting type t_Response".

Following is the DE-serialization code.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(t_Response));
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
                {
                    t_Response obj_t_Response = (t_Response)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    t_ResponseDetails responseDetails = (t_ResponseDetails)obj_t_Response.Item;
                    if (responseDetails.Items.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        t_SearchItemInformationResponse searchItemInfoResp = (t_SearchItemInformationResponse)responseDetails.Items[0];

                        t_ItemDetails itemDetails = (t_ItemDetails)searchItemInfoResp.Item;
                        t_ItemDetail[] itemDetail = (t_ItemDetail[])itemDetails.ItemDetail;
                        if (itemDetail.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            t_City city = itemDetail[0].City;
                            t_Location[] location = itemDetail[0].LocationDetails;
                            t_Item item = itemDetail[0].Item;
                            t_HotelInformation hotelInformation = (t_HotelInformation)itemDetail[0].Item1;
                            //hotelInformation.AddressLines.
                            //hotelInformati
                        }
                    }                        
                }
```

The class structure for response class is

```
 public partial class t_Response
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}



public partial class t_Response
{
    private object itemField;

    private string requestReferenceField;

    private string responseReferenceField;

    private string responseSequenceField;

    private System.DateTime timeStampField;

    private bool timeStampFieldSpecified;


    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Errors", typeof(t_Errors), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ResponseDetails", typeof(t_ResponseDetails), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
    public object Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string RequestReference
    {
        get
        {
            return this.requestReferenceField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.requestReferenceField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string ResponseReference
    {
        get
        {
            return this.responseReferenceField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.responseReferenceField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType = "integer")]
    public string ResponseSequence
    {
        get
        {
            return this.responseSequenceField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.responseSequenceField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public System.DateTime TimeStamp
    {
        get
        {
            return this.timeStampField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.timeStampField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool TimeStampSpecified
    {
        get
        {
            return this.timeStampFieldSpecified;
        }
        set
        {
            this.timeStampFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please send us the code and the exact error so we can pinpoint the problem.

Comment: The type mismatch as you added a custom primary key.

Comment: Add an [XmlIgnore] annotation on the primary keys of the POCO.

Comment: thanks stefan, edited question for code and error

Comment: thanks AlexC let me try your suggestion

Comment: thanks AlexC your suggestion has helped, after adding attribute of xmlIgnore it is De-serializing successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This `Mismatch exception` occurs when you have once created your database using code first technique, and then later you [add a new attribute to your class. (i.e Id in your case). In this case, database need to be updated (some migration tools etc).](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EntityFrameworkCodeFirstMigrationsAlphaNuGetPackageOfTheWeek10.aspx) Or you may give a try on a new class and stuff. (don't forget to place *ID* property this time).

Comment: thanks zeeshan, class structure is not created rather provided by xsd schema so don't have option to add id next time :)

Comment: @MuzaffarAli No, i mean, try by creating ID field in your model class, to which your schema is mapped by deserialization. (or i'm missing something?)

Comment: i was having problem of De-serialization after adding id column, xmlignore has helped.